# How to use the move function under curses.h

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

It doesn't print at coordinates y=10, x=20.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main()
{
    initscr();
    refresh();
    WINDOW *win;
    wmove(win, 10, 20);
    refresh();
    printf("hi\n"); 
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute it like this...

```
./a.out > op_file
```

This is what is op_file

```
[?1049h[1;24r(B[m[4l[?7h[H[2J-1
hi
```

Can someone explain...??

Comment: I have edited the question. Can someone please try to answer now...??

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**This works.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main()
{
    initscr();
    refresh();

    WINDOW *win;
    win = stdscr;

    wmove(win, 10, 10);

    refresh();
    printf("hi\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks to @interjay.

Comment: Still no endwin() - it may work in your case but it is not proper ncurses code. The first refresh() call is superfluous. The variable assignment of stdscr as well. The usage of printf is just wrong as explained above. For that you can just use ANSI escape sequences instead of curses which will work the way you probably want.

Answer (score 3):

You must use `initscr()` function to initialize the screen and `endwin()` at the end to close the window...

If you `move()`, you must use `refresh()` or the cursor won't move physically.

Comment: Nop i'm not going to code for you, I can help you finding your way but I won't code for you

Answer (score 1):

To move the cursor to a new position on a window, use the function int wmove(WINDOW *win, int y, int x)

wmove(win, y, x);
where (x, y) are the coordinates of the new position in the window. If the window has nlines lines and ncolumns columns, then

```
  0 <= y < nlines
  0 <= x < ncolumns
```

Refresh. The actual cursor motion is not shown on the screen untill you do a wrefresh(win).

**move(y, x) is equivalent to the wmove(stdscr, y, x)**.`

The move() and wmove() functions move the cursor associated with the current or specified window to (y, x) relative to the window's origin. This function does not move the terminal's cursor until the next refresh operation.

To move the logical cursor in the user-defined window my_window to the coordinates y = 5, x = 10, use :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>

    int main(){
        refresh();//First refresh
        WINDOW *my_window;
        int a = wmove(my_window, 5, 10);
        refresh();////Second refresh
        printf("%d\n",a);
        printf("hi\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Still `a` is -1. This is what I do after compiling. `./a.out > op_file`

Answer (score 0):

The output

```
[?1049h[1;24r(B[m[4l[?7h[H[2J-1
hi
```

shows the *printable* characters written.  If you look at the complete text, e.g., in a text-editor, there'll be ASCII *escape* characters before the **`[`** and **`(`** characters since that's part of the escape sequence.

Your example doesn't show *cursor movement* (aside from the *home* position which you'd see as **`^[[H`** near the end) because there's no reason for the curses library to actually move the cursor.  If you had asked it to read a character, e.g., using **`getch`**, it would have to stop and decide where the cursor should be — and your **`wmove`** would do that — except that **`win`** is not initialized.  The simplest thing to do is use **`stdscr`** (which is initialized by `initscr`).

The program quits curses calls without doing an **`endwin`** (which leaves the terminal in *raw mode*).  The data does get written to the screen with the **`refresh`** call.  The data written with **`printf`** happens to come out in the right order, but that's only coincidental since it does not use the same output buffering as ncurses.

Both of the other answers contain similar errors.