# The Curses library `move` function gives an error

Tags: curses

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    move(12, 6);
    printf("hello world !");
    return 0;
}
```

The `move` function gives an error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour], and read [ask], and use the formatting. To get help you'll need to include your intentions, your code, and the error or unexpected behaviour you're getting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use the move function under curses.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51188836/how-to-use-the-move-function-under-curses-h)

Comment: I've edited your question somewhat to make the title more in line with expectations and to apply code formatting - please can you edit it further to include the exact error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ : Difference between linking library and adding include directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096152/c-difference-between-linking-library-and-adding-include-directories)

Answer (score 0):

`move` returns an error (`ERR` is `-1`) because curses was not initialized, e.g., using `initscr`.

That `printf` will do nothing useful in curses; you should replace that with `printw` (and unless your program waits for input, e.g., by calling `getch`, will exit immediately).

The program also should call `endwin` (to undo the screen-initialization, making the terminal work properly).

Comment: Thank you for your help, i try what you Said but i still got the same error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 "_initscr", referenced from:
      _main in curse-199ccd.o"